# xml content: one line per entry

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML:

```
<root>

<entry id="1">
<content>TEXT</content>
</entry>

<entry id="2">
<content>TEXT</content>
</entry>

<entry id="3">
<content>TEXT</content>
</entry>

<root>
```

How I can transforme it (with xslt) for to have all "entry" on 1 line such as:

```
<root>

<entry id="1"><content>TEXT</content></entry>
<entry id="2"><content>TEXT</content></entry>
<entry id="3"><content>TEXT</content></entry>

<root>
```

thanks for your ideas

Comment: You should not care about your XML layout. Really, if your XML layout makes any difference you're doing something wrong. Use `<xsl:output indent="yes" />` and move on.

Answer (score 1):

AS I said in my comment above, XML layout should not matter to you. Any application that works with XML should only care about the DOM tree, not about the XML source layout. Adding or removing insignificant white space must not break anything or change any behavior.

If you really, positively have to, then you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry/text()[normalize-space() = '']" />
    <xsl:template match="text()[
        normalize-space() = '' 
        and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::entry]
        and following-sibling::*[1][self::entry]
    ]">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

While this produces the desired XML, it's really a useless no-op that has no more than academic value, showing some of the things you can do with XPath. Please, don't *actually* do it.

Comment: Awesome.  You pointed out that it's a bad idea, but came through with the code.  You earned that upvote.

Comment: @austin I think the code shows nicely that this a pointless exercise.

Comment: I'm probably going to come back to this in case I get asked by a boss to "make the XML prettier".

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way might be just to use the xsl:strip-spaces instruction to strip the white space from the incoming XML document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"    
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon"    >

<xsl:strip-space elements="entry"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How well this works will depend on how you are serializing the output XML.